# Excel Hyperlinks between sheets and color formatting based on other cell data

Tags: excel, date, hyperlink, conditional-statements, max

I am using Microsoft office 365 ProPlus version 1701 build 7766.2092

I am looking to take the max date of a range within sheet 1 and hyperlink it to sheet 2.

`=HYPERLINK((MAX(Validation!I6:U6)),MAX(Validation!I6:U6))`

All the dates in sheet1 are hyperlinked to another excel or pdf. I can obtain the most recent date, but the actual link cannot open on sheet2.

How can I link the max date within a range to another sheet successfully?

Next, I am looking to highlight the particular link/date in sheet 2 if it falls with a specific date range base on the cell right  next to it.

`Cell A1=monthly Cell A2= the hyperlinked date`

If A1 is monthly, I want the cell B1 to be highlighted green if it falls under 30 days and yellow if it is over. If A3 is weekly, I want the cell A3 to be highlighted green if it falls under 7 days and yellow if it is over.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Q1 (Hyperlinks) - As far as I know, you can't retrieve the URL from a hyperlink within a cell.  If the URL is something you can work out from the value in the cell e.g. the sheet name is 'January' you could make some kind of formula to obtain the month of the date in the cell.  Otherwise, you're going to have to use VBA.

Q2 (Formatting) - I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here.  If you can give us an example of the tables that might help.

Comment: I would assume you could use vba to make the links work. I am unsure on what that may look like..            As far as Q2: cell A1 has the text monthly, cell A2 has the text weekly, Cell A3:A40 alternates monthly/weekly. Cell B1:B40 has its own date. Should that date be next to monthly, I want it to be highlighted green if it falls within 30 days of today date. yellow if it is outside that date. Weekly in and outside of 7 days..